# Parse text file line by line with specified separators

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, text-files

I need to get the numbers from each line of the text file using boost:

```
d$+$B$ 0.0   000 000 000    1.0   255 255 255
```

something like :

```
0.0   000 000 000    1.0   255 255 255
```

In Qt, it is smth like that:

```
 QString data = input->readLine();
 o_name = data.section('$', 0, 2);
 QStringList dataLst = data.section('$', 3, 3).split(' ', QString::SkipEmptyParts);
while(!dataLst.isEmpty() )
//process
```

**What is the equivalent alg in boost?**

So far, I have only this:

```
boost::iostreams::basic_file<float>( filename,  std::ios_base::in  );
```

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "C++ read file parse variable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short code snippet using boost regular expressions. I was trying to get the same working using c++11, but seems it's not supported by gcc 4.8.2 yet: [GCC GNU](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011)

```
  std::ifstream ifStreamObject("test", std::ifstream::in);
  if (!ifStreamObject.is_open())
  {
    // nothing to do
    return -1;
  }
  std::string line;
  boost::regex e("\\s+"); // split on whitespaces
  boost::sregex_token_iterator j;
  while (std::getline(ifStreamObject, line))  
  {
    boost::sregex_token_iterator i(line.begin(), line.end(), e, -1);

    while(i!=j)
    {
      // display the tokens for now.. process the data here
      cout << *i++ << endl;
    }
  }
```

output:

```
d$+$B$
0.0
000
000
000
1.0
255
255
255
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Boost Spirit:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>
#include <fstream>
using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    std::string oname;
    std::vector<double> numbers;

    if (std::ifstream("input.txt") >> std::noskipws 
            >> match(*~char_('$') > '$')
            >> match(*~char_('$') > '$')
            >> match(*~char_('$') > '$', oname)
            >> phrase_match(*double_, blank, numbers))
    {
        std::cout << oname << ": parsed " << numbers.size() << " numbers: ";
        for(auto d : numbers) 
            std::cout << d << " ";
    }
}
```

It prints

```
B: parsed 8 numbers: 0 0 0 0 1 255 255 255
```

for your sample line. See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9253f869da00e88)**

> **Update** I just noticed you want the whole "d$+$B$" to be parsed as oname:
>
> ```
>         >> match(raw [ repeat(3) [ *~char_('$') > '$' ] ], oname)
> ```
>
> or alternatively just
>
> ```
>         >> match(*~char_('$') > char_('$'), oname)
>         >> match(*~char_('$') > char_('$'), oname)
>         >> match(*~char_('$') > char_('$'), oname)
> ```
>
> which would concatenate into `oname`

Comment: could you please tell how this thing (std::ifstream("input.txt") >> std::noskipws 
            >> match(*~char_('$') > '$')
            >> match(*~char_('$') > '$')
            >> match(*~char_('$') > '$', oname)
            >> phrase_match(*double_, blank, numbers)) works? or a link to doc, I could not find. especially > phrase_match(*double_, blank, numbers)) what are the params?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parse_api/stream_api.html